# Are there algebraic objects in which "associativity" holds only up to some finite $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I don't know if this question doesn't answer itself.

Generally, when a binary operation $\circ:S\times{S}\to{S}$ is called associative, it is usually sufficient to state:

$$a\circ(b\circ{c})=(a\circ{b})\circ{c}$$

defines the operation as associative.

I don't know whether, if the above identity holds, it can be proven by induction that all parenthesizations of an expression containing are equivalent. I therefore ask the following in some ignorance:

> Are there algebraic objects in which "associativity" holds only up to some finite $n$?

That is:

> Are there algebraic objects in which, e.g, $a\circ(b\circ{c})=(a\circ{b})\circ{c}$  holds but $a\circ({b}(\circ{c}(\circ{d})))=(((a\circ{b})\circ{c})\circ{d}$ does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by induction associativity implies higher-arity associativity.

For example, if I want to show that $a\circ (b\circ (c\circ d))=((a\circ b)\circ c)\circ d,$ I can argue as follows:

- $a\circ (b\circ (c\circ d))=(a\circ b)\circ (c\circ d)$.
- $(a\circ b)\circ (c\circ d)=((a\circ b)\circ c)\circ d$.

The full proof by induction is a good exercise.

---

There are, however, important weak forms of associativity coming from restrictions on the *elements*, e.g. [power associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_associativity) and [alternativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_algebra). Note that for weaker versions of associativity, the "full" version may *not* follow from the "basic" version, e.g. in the case of power associativity it's not enough to just demand $x\circ (x\circ x)=(x\circ x)\circ x$ for all $x$.